# Problems installing base64

Tags: go

I'm trying to install base64 for compiling some Go code.

From https://github.com/libgoost/encoding-base64

using go get -v goost.org/encoding/base64.

**My go version** go1.15.7 linux/amd64, (and I want to compile for aarch64 embedded system later).

**This is my error**: "go: goost.org/encoding/base64@v0.0.0-20190924451742-cd6f754436c10: unrecognized import path "goost.org/encoding/base64": parse https://goost.org/encoding/base64?go-get=1: no go-import meta tags ()"

*What is the problem?*

Comment: Not really solving your problem, but why are you not using builtin bas64? https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/base64/

Comment: That URL is broken. You could just import `https://github.com/libgoost/encoding-base64` directly, but I don't see why you wouldn't just use the stdlib `encoding/base64` package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the `goost.org` website does not support `go get`  standard despite what's written in the README.

You could either import from `github.com/libgoost/encoding-base64` or use the standard library `encoding/base64`